# Left Layout disappears whenever datatable is added within the center Pane of primeFaces Layout

Tags: jsf-2

Im using Jsf 2.0 and primefaces exstensions component  pe:layout to create a page with left navigation menu bar ,bottom footer and center pane for content everthing works fine but when ever i add primefaces datatable (p:datatable) in the center pane the header and footer layouts are preserved but the left pane disappears and the center pane occupies the entire page. I tried setting width and height of the datatable but nothing seems to work. The page displays correctly without datatable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please find below the code with datatable:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<ui:composition template="/templates/showcaseLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="centerContent">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Jan Sampark"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="centerContent">
           Welcome to the Menu Page.
               <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

        </h:panelGroup>
       <p:tabView id="tabView">

    <p:tab id="tab1" title="Godfather Part I">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            <p:graphicImage id="tab1Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather1.jpg" />
            <h:outputText id="tab1Text"
                value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding.
                His beloved son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business. T
                hrough Michael's life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head of the family, kind and benevolent to those who give respect,
                but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the family." />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tab2" title="Godfather Part II">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            <p:graphicImage id="tab2Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather2.jpg" />
            <h:outputText id="tab2Text" value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary continuation and sequel to his landmark 1972 film, The_Godfather, parallels the young Vito Corleone's rise with his son Michael's spiritual fall, deepening The_Godfather's depiction of the dark side of the American dream.
            In the early 1900s, the child Vito flees his Sicilian village for America after the local Mafia kills his family. Vito struggles to make a living, legally or illegally, for his wife and growing brood in Little Italy,
            killing the local Black Hand Fanucci after he demands his customary cut of the tyro's business. With Fanucci gone, Vito's communal stature grows."/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tab3" title="Godfather Part III">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            <p:graphicImage id="tab3Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />
            <h:outputText id="tab3Text" value="After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.
                Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate."/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>

</p:tabView>



  <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="centerContent">
            <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}" id="carList" editable="true" style="table-layout: fixed"
               scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" scrollWidth="300">
        <f:facet name="header">
            In-Cell Editing
        </f:facet>

<!--         <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onEdit}" update=":form:messages" /> -->
<!--         <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{tableBean.onCancel}" update=":form:messages" /> -->

        <p:column headerText="Model" >
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{car.model}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="Manufacturer">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.manufacturer}" >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{tableBean.manufacturers}"
                            var="man" 
                            itemLabel="#{man}"
                            itemValue="#{man}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Color">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.color}" >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{tableBean.colors}"
                            var="color" 
                            itemLabel="#{color}"
                            itemValue="#{color}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Options">
            <p:rowEditor />
        </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="docuTable">
        <ui:include src="/sections/shared/documentation.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="tagName" value="timeline"/>
        </ui:include>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```